# I am having difficulty with the algebra related to a coordinate geometry question.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-transformation, homothety

A line is drawn through the point $A=(1,2)$ to cut the line $2y = 3x-5$ in $P$ and the line $x+y = 12$ in $Q$.  If $AQ$ = $2AP$, find the coordinates of $P$ and $Q$.

Comment: Please show us your work so far, so we can help you. What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: I have drawn a diagram showing the three lines.  I assume that AQ is a diameter and AP is a radius of a circle.  I can obtain an equation for the length of AQ and AP.  e.g. AQ = square root of (1-X)+ 2-Y).  I can substitute a value for Y into this equations' e.g Y = -X+12.  I can't get a quadratic equation to get a value for X and then substitute this to get a value for Y.

Answer (score 1):

**Case 1:**

Since $Q(a,12-a)$ is on line $x+y=12$ then the midpoint $P({a+1\over 2},{14-a\over 2})$ of $AQ$ is on line $2y=3x-5$. So we have:

$$2{14-a\over 2} =3{a+1\over 2} -5$$

So we have $a= 7$ and thus $Q(7,5)$ and $P(4,{7\over 2})$.

**Case 2:**

The midpoint $P'({a+1\over 2},{14-a\over 2})$ of $AQ$ is not on line $2y=3x-5$.
Since $A$ is the midpoint of $PP'$ we have $P({3-a\over 2},{a-6\over 2})$. Since $P$ is on $2y=3x-5$ we have:

$$2{a-6\over 2} =3{3-a\over 2}-5$$

so $a= {5\over 4}$...

Comment: The answer is (2/5, -19/10) and (2 & 1/5, 9 & 4/5). but I don't know how to get this answer.

Comment: I don't think that $P$ is necessarily the midpoint of $AQ$. It's true only if $P$ and $Q$ are on the same side

Comment: Thanks John, Lab and Andrei I appreciate the time you have taken to help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

WLOG the equation of any straight line passing through $A(1,2)$ can be written as $$m=\dfrac{y-2}{x-1}$$

Find its intersections with the other two lines in terms of $m$

Now use $$AQ=2AP$$

Answer (score 0):

A generic point of line $p:2y=3x-5$ has coordinates $P\left(t,\dfrac{3t-5}{2}\right)$

On line $q:x+y=12$  generic point is $Q(u,12-u)$

we have $$AP=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{ \left|13 t^2-62 t+85\right|},\;AQ=\sqrt{2 u^2-22 u+101}$$

$AQ=2AP$ if 
$$\sqrt{2 u^2-22 u+101}=\sqrt{ \left|13 t^2-62 t+85\right|}$$
so it can be
$$2 u^2-22 u+101=13 t^2-62 t+85\lor 2 u^2-22 u+101=-(13 t^2-62 t+85)$$
with the condition that $A,P,Q$ are collinear. Cross product of vectors $\vec {AP},\;\vec {PQ}$ is null.

that is $$-5 t u+23 t+11 u-29=0$$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 2 u^2-22 u+101=13 t^2-62 t+85 \\
 -5 t u+23 t+11 u-29=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$t = 2/5, u = 11/5, t = 4, u =7$

So we have the points

$$P_1\left(\dfrac{2}{5},-\dfrac{19}{10}\right),\;Q_1\left(\frac{11}{5},\frac{49}{5}\right)$$

$$P_2\left(4,\frac{7}{2}\right),\;Q_2(7,5)$$

The second equations gives no real results

Hope this helps

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  I have laboured long and hard over this one with no success.  So easy if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Honestly I started as lab bhattacharie but after 1/2 hour efforts I realized that awful things were coming out *things you people wouldn't believe,...* Systems of $12$nd degree and similar, so I changed my solution and now it works pretty well, thank you..

Comment: Also thanks John, Lab and Andrei I appreciate the time you have taken to help me with this problem.

Answer (score -1):

Hint - 
As AQ=2AP hence AP=PQ. Therefore use midpoint formula
Now consider P($x_1 , y_1$) and Q($x_2 ,y_2$). 
Now slope AP= slope PQ = slope AQ . Now  P($x_1 , y_1$) satisfy equation 1 and and Q of another one. I hope you can solve forward. 
Remember it's just a hint. Next time write what y you have tried